# Lodown for updated NPPES NPI Extraction

Tags: r, survey

I'm using ajdamico's lodown package in R. First off, let me say that this package is amazing, so thank you to Anthony. Having successfully run the script in the past I have two questions:

1. NPPES released a July file. When running the script on this latest release I'm seeing only June data. That is, I don't see any records that were updated in July though I know records had been updated in July, observed by the weekly files NPPES releases. Any idea why this is the case? I suspect it's at least partly due to the July zip files containing much more data than was provided historically.
2. In light of the zip file now containing many more files, how do I direct the script which file to extract?

Full script below, before any subsetting is applied:

```
    get_catalog_nppes <-
        function( data_name = "nppes" , output_dir , ... ){

        # read in the whole NPI files page
        npi.datapage <- suppressWarnings( readLines( "http://download.cms.gov/nppes/NPI_Files.html" ) )

        # find the first line containing the data dissemination link
        npi.dataline <- npi.datapage[ grep( "NPPES_Data_Dissemination_" , npi.datapage ) ][1]

        # pull out the zipped file's name from that line
        fn <- paste0( "http://download.cms.gov/nppes/" , gsub( "(.*)(NPPES_Data_Dissemination_.*\\.zip)(.*)$" , "\\2" , npi.dataline ) )

        catalog <-
            data.frame(
                full_url = fn ,
                output_filename = paste0( output_dir , "/nppes.csv" ) ,
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE
            )

        catalog

    }


    lodown_nppes <-
        function( data_name = "nppes" , catalog , path_to_7za = '7za' , ... ){

            on.exit( print( catalog ) )

            if( nrow( catalog ) != 1 ) stop( "nppes catalog must be exactly one record" )

            if( ( .Platform$OS.type != 'windows' ) && ( system( paste0('"', path_to_7za , '" -h' ) ) != 0 ) ) stop( "you need to install 7-zip.  if you already have it, include a path_to_7za='/directory/7za' parameter" )

            tf <- tempfile()

            download.file( catalog$full_url , tf , mode = 'wb' )

            # extract the file, platform-specific
            if ( .Platform$OS.type == 'windows' ){

                unzipped_files <- unzip_warn_fail( tf , exdir = tempdir() )

            } else {

                # build the string to send to the terminal on non-windows systems
                dos.command <- paste0( '"' , path_to_7za , '" x ' , tf , ' -o"' , tempdir() , '"' )
                system( dos.command )
                unzipped_files <- list.files( tempdir() , full.names = TRUE , recursive = TRUE )

            }

            csv.file <- unzipped_files[ grepl( '\\.csv$' , basename( unzipped_files ) , ignore.case = TRUE ) & !grepl( 'FileHeader' , basename( unzipped_files ) , ignore.case = TRUE ) ]

            file.copy( csv.file , catalog$output_filename )

            catalog$case_count <- R.utils::countLines( csv.file ) - 1

            file.remove( unzipped_files , tf )

            on.exit()

            catalog

        }


##Load Dataset
column_names <-
  names( 
    read.csv( 
      file.path( path.expand( "~" ) , "NPPES" , "nppes.csv" ) , 
      nrow = 1 )[ FALSE , , ] 
  )

##Load Dataframe
column_names <-
  names( 
    read.csv( 
      file.path( path.expand( "~" ) , "NPPES" , "nppes.csv" ) , 
      nrow = 1 )[ FALSE , , ] 
  )

column_names <- gsub( "\\." , "_" , tolower( column_names ) )

column_types <-
  ifelse( 
    grepl( "npi" , column_names ) & 
      !grepl( "npi|codified|first|last|blergh|whistle|rule|exist|orange|way|brown|houses|outrageous|boring|substance|superficial|good|fancy|sneaky|terrific|paint|nasty|gentle|decorous|smile", column_names ) , 
    'n' , 'c' 
  )

columns_to_import <-
  c( "npi","entity_type_code","provider_business_mailing_address_postal_code","last_update_date","npi_deactivation_reason_code","npi_deactivation_date","npi_reactivation_date","authorized_official_last_name","authorized_official_first_name","healthcare_provider_taxonomy_code_1","healthcare_provider_taxonomy_code_2","healthcare_provider_taxonomy_code_3","healthcare_provider_taxonomy_code_4","healthcare_provider_taxonomy_code_5","healthcare_provider_taxonomy_code_6","healthcare_provider_taxonomy_code_7","healthcare_provider_taxonomy_code_8","healthcare_provider_taxonomy_code_9","healthcare_provider_taxonomy_code_10","healthcare_provider_taxonomy_code_11","healthcare_provider_taxonomy_code_12","healthcare_provider_taxonomy_code_13","healthcare_provider_taxonomy_code_14","healthcare_provider_taxonomy_code_15","is_sole_proprietor"
  )

stopifnot( all( columns_to_import %in% column_names ) )

columns_to_import <-
  columns_to_import[ order( match( columns_to_import , column_names ) ) ]

nppes <- 
  data.frame( 
    readr::read_csv( 
      file.path( path.expand( "~" ) , "NPPES" , 
                 "nppes.csv" ) , 
      col_names = columns_to_import , 
      col_types = 
        paste0( 
          ifelse( column_names %in% columns_to_import , column_types , '_' ) , 
          collapse = "" 
        ) ,
      skip = 1
    ) 
  )
```

Comment: hi, looks like they've modified the structure.  i've updated `library(lodown)` accordingly

Comment: @AnthonyDamico: Many thanks. However, I uninstalled lodown reinstalled it, subsetted the data per my needs, and it seems to still only be pulling data from the June 2018 dissemination file instead of the more recent July file. Any idea why this might be the case?

Comment: @AnthonyDamico. I wanted to follow up on my last note. Thanks!